# how can I summarize checked column with django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a table with some columns. One column is a checkboxcolumn. 
So, how can I summarize the "quantity" columns that checkboxcolumn is checked?
I appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the number of checked rows?

Comment: I have 3 columns: "id, value and select". The third column is a checkcolum. When I check this column i´d like to sumarize value column.

Comment: Do you want to summarize in the browser, or in python?

Comment: Right now I need to know in python. But it will be good to know both,

Comment: So, I need to show the total in the same screen. I do not know what will be the best to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [django-tables2 docs on `CheckBoxColumn` mention](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#checkboxcolumn):

> You might expect that you could select multiple checkboxes in the rendered table and then do something with that. This functionality is not implemented. If you want something to actually happen, you will need to implement that yourself.

So django-tables2 doesn't have something build in, we have to write something ourselves. That makes this more of a JavaScript/HTML question, but anyway, let's see if we can create a table for this model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    population = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

This is a basic table, adding an empty footer to the table by adding a footer argument to one of the columns. We will use this footer later to put the calculated population sum in.

```
class CheckboxTable(tables.Table):
    select = tables.CheckBoxColumn(empty_values=(), footer='')

    population = tables.Column(attrs={'cell': {'class': 'population'}})

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        fields = ('select', 'name', 'population')
```

Now, the template. I used jQuery, to quickly create a function to calculate the sum. This function is executed every time the `change` event is fired on one of the checkboxes, and on page load.

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

    // calculate the sum of the population column for the selected rows.
    function update_sum() {
        var sum = 0;
        // loop over each checkbox within <tbody>
        $('tbody input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            // if the checkbox is checked
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                // find the contents of the population column, convert
                // it to integer and add it to the total.
                sum += parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('.population').html());
            }
        });
        // add the sum to the footer cell in the population column.
        $('tfoot .population').html(sum);
    }

    // update the sum after each change
    $('tbody input[type=checkbox]').on('change', update_sum);

    // update the sum initially.
    update_sum();
});
</script>
```

I [added code similar to this](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/commit/3835f3abfd87c88dcd304c4f361dc90d582de473) to the django-tables2 example application.

Comment: I got it!  I incluse valorfloat = parseFloat(valor.replace(",", ".")); Thanks !!!!!!